# How to make different Time-based keys for a dictionary?

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, timestamp

I need to store some input information as a value in a dictionary. It will be very convenient to store the input under a timestamp key. I try this for example:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = '%s.%02d.%sX%s%s%s' % (when.day, when.month, when.year, when.minute, when.second, when.microsecond) #

someDict = {}
for iter in range(5):
    someValue = raw_input('Value:')
    print date
    someDict[date] = someValue
```

As a result i have:

```
Value: 11111
12.07.2014X3456671342
Value: 22222
12.07.2014X3456671342
Value: 33333
12.07.2014X3456671342
Value: 44444
12.07.2014X3456671342
Value: 55555
12.07.2014X3456671342
```

And, of course, the `len(someDict)` is `1`, instead of `5` needed.
The perfect output should be something like:

```
someDict = {'12.07.2014X-----': 11111, '12.07.2014X-----': 22222, '12.07.2014X-----': 33333} #Where ----- is a time-based number.
```

And so on, with an ability to add new Key/Values

Comment: Why not use the [pandas timeseries functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)? Leave a comment if this is of interest and I'll post an answer with code.

Comment: why not use the raw input as key ? i mean someDict[someValue] = date

Comment: @hd1 Why just not to update a 'date' variable anytime I enter a loop? I know, the simple way without third party modules should exist.

Comment: A dictionary contains only 1 value per key.

Comment: @ΒασιληςΙωσηφιδης Cos raw_input will be pretty the same all the time... and dicts with duplicate keys are not allowed

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's why i need different keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
import datetime

someDict = {}
for iter in range(5):
    date_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    date = '%s.%02d.%sX%s%s%s' % (date_now.day, date_now.month, date_now.year, date_now.minute, date_now.second, date_now.microsecond) #

    someValue = raw_input('Value:')
    print date
    someDict[date] = someValue
```

Comment: That is prone to race condition on fast computers.

Comment: And the clock will jump back once a year when run in a time zone with daylight saving time.  Better use `utcnow()` instead of `now()`.

Comment: seems to be working, when including a variable inside a loop. TY

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

d = {}
val = 0
while True:
    sleep(1)
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%s')
    d[now] = val
    val += 1
    print(d)
```

That something like this might work doesn't mean it's wise to use datetime objects as dict keys..

Maybe it would be better to add your values to a list as tuples with a timestamp; that way you know both the order in which the values came in and the time:

```
from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
from time import sleep                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

data = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
val = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
for i in range(100):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    sleep(.001)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%s')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    data.append((val, now))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    val += 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    print(data)
```

Comment: Use now.strftime('%s') to get

Comment: @hd1 Could you please make a more expanded answer?

Comment: @Vanechka if it doesn't work: can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: @Vanechka: ok.. added a print statement.. :) You may want to change the sleep to 1 second though...

Comment: @Vanechka: and another edit: now using strings instead of date time instances

Comment: i added it as well. I think that your code doesn't run in my shell is cos of the Python versions... i use 2.7.7

Comment: And how could i extract a real date from that list or dict?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from datetime import datetime
date = '%s.%02d.%sX%s%s%s' % (when.day, when.month, when.year, when.minute, when.second, when.microsecond) #

someDict = {}
old_date = None
counter = 0

for iter in range(5):
    if old_date != date:
        counter = 0
        old_date = date

    key = '%s%08d' % (date, counter)
    counter += 1

    someValue = raw_input('Value:')
    print key
    someDict[key] = someValue
```

Comment: Good idea how not to fix, but to avoid a problem. Thank you.

Comment: I hope it won't)) TY.

Comment: Where is `when` defined?

Comment: There where it was defined in the OP's code: nowhere.

Comment: What if the date changes when in between loop?

Comment: @BlackJack i missed to include it here, sorry. 'when = datetime.now()'

Comment: @Aedil it might, but i need it to be changed inside... time passes anyway, so the variable should change... i think...

Comment: @Vanechka: As commented on another anwser: Beware of daylight savings time and use `utcnow()` instead of `now()`.

Comment: In this case pretty much all the keys will have same date value, only thing differ them is the counter you added ...